# The focus and click event in nested layout

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Click"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

I want the whole `RelativeLayout` focused when the button is clicked, the above codes worked as expected.

No matter I click the text or the blank area, the `RelativeLayout` will change its background color.

However when I add a Onclick listener to the button like this:

```
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
```

Then the behavor changed when I click the button, if I click the button the layout of its parent does not change, only if I click the blank area , the `RelativeLayout` will change the background.

See this picture(they are all captured when the mouse is pressed):

[image]

I wonder if there is any docs to explain this phenomenon?

Now, I have to add the click listener to the `RelativeLayout` directly, any alternative?

---

update the complete layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Detail"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="Action1" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:text="|"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="Action2" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I have two problems:

1 The button does not change its background when clicked on the text.

2 If I click the blank area of `btn1`, then both of the `btn1` and `btn2` will change its background.

Effect at the moment:

[image]

Comment: IF you want a behaviour like this, you should not be having two views.. any particular reason why you want two view? One hack would be to make button, `match_parent`

Comment: Because the `RelativeLayout` have a parent which have a background color when focused, I do not want this background cover the `Button`

Comment: Umm.. it would be great if you post full xml. I want to see the layout (eg. the parent you are talking about).. to debug..

Answer (score 0):

If the view is not clickable then [setOnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) will make it clickable.  The alternative would probably be direct manipulation of the [clickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When the child element consumes the click events then its parent layout wont be delegated the action, if you want the parent RelativeLayout to be handling the click events then override the click listener for RelativeLayout, not the button.